# Appbar image is not showing

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

I have an appbar in a windows phone 8 application. Here is the xaml. The image is 48 by 48 cropped. Here are the properties for the image Build action is "content" and resource is "Copy if newer". Problem is I am seeing a white color background with a squared border for the image but I am unable to see the actual content of the image. Please help.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar Opacity="1.0" IsMenuEnabled="True" Mode="Minimized" IsVisible="True">

            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="Directions" IconUri="/image/direction.jpg" Click="ApplicationBarIconButton_Click_1" />


        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Comment: i know it may sound dumb but have you checked the Icon uri string that it does matches where the image is? isnt it /image(s) ?

Comment: Yea the path is right its image folder.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried doing it like this??

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar Opacity="1.0" IsMenuEnabled="True" Mode="Minimized" IsVisible="True">
   <shell:ApplicationBar.Buttons>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Click="ApplicationBarIconButton_Click_1" Text="Directions" IconUri="/image/direction.jpg"  />

  <shell:ApplicationBar.Buttons>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

also try changing the image format to png

Comment: I tried various things it still dosent show for some reason. Even if i say ~/image/direction.jpg on it dosent display that white blank image. It just shows a circle with an into mark in it.